# spark.driver.memory has no effect?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, configuration, aws-glue

I'm running this [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-glue-libs) in local mode to do some local development for AWS Glue using PySpark/Jupyter notebook as my dev IDE. Starting the Spark application and then going to Spark UI to look at my environment variables I see

> spark.driver.memory 1000M

I navigate to `/home/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/conf/spark-defaults.conf` and add this line based on the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties):

> spark.driver.memory 8g

restart the Docker container, check my environment variables again and it's still set to `1000M`.

Any ideas on what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to see spark.driver.memory under environment tab of spark UI unless the property got overridden. I think this property got changed in between to 1000M, check where it got changed.

Let's say you added 8g as driver memory in spark-defaults.conf. When you pass 10g as driver memory when launching spark application using `spark-submit --conf` command, spark will consider 10g as driver memory and you can see that on UI also.